# Polymer repeating template issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, polymer

Sorry for the vague title, I wasn't sure how to phrase what I mean.

**Background:** I'm making a single page application for my company, I was building in polymer 0.56, and am just trying to upgrade to 1.0.

**Issue:** When cloning content (clean HTML) into my main "view" div, some polymer elements (buttons) are repeatedly nesting themselves causing UI bugs shown:

[image: Logout button with 2 UI buttons]

**The generated code:**

[image: The bad generated UI code]

This only happens when I .clone() the content, or use .innerHTML to copy it into the view div. e.g.

```
mainDiv.append($(cleanHTML).clone());
```

And the odd bit is that this issue does not occur when the following is used:

```
mainDiv.append(cleanHTML);
```

**This gives:**

[image: What the button should look like]
[image: Good code]

The main div is always cleaned before I add anything. I want to avoid directly using the object cleanHTML if possible (hence why I was trying to .clone()) does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: I have a vague hunch that this may have something to do with how Polymer abstracts the DOM. I would recommend that you provide a more complete snippet of the source (both JS and HTML) that may clarify what role `cleanHTML` and `mainDiv` play, as well as provide better context.

Comment: It's pretty safe bet to not use clone() for rendered content when working with polymer. Maybe an example of what you are trying to achieve would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  <paper-button>
  <iron-icon icon="favorite"></iron-icon>
  Logout
  </paper-button>
```

and yes, polymer does make it overlapping if CSS conflicts, so I'd prefer using the custom button which can be modified